# How to add Testcase dynamically to TestSuite and run that testsuite using JUNIT?

Tags: java, junit4

I am able to run the testsuite by adding class statically. like

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
    SecondTestCase.class,
    ThridTestCase.class,
    SixthTestCase.class,
    FifthTestCase.class,
    EightTestCase.class,
    FirstTestCase.class,
    SeventhTestCase.class

})
public class TestSuite {

}
```

But i am facing difficulty when i have to pass classes dynamically.

I am having the GUI consists of all my test case that consists of check box for each test case. I will select test case from those boxes and want to run selected one.

Any Body have any idea about this? how to do this

Comment: Put a wrapper around each test case that can be dynamically selected. Have the wrapper test whether it was selected, and return SKIP if it was not.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i am new in JUNIT any Demo Useing current scenirio